# Using slice() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, slice

I have difficulty understanding the use of `slice()` wrt to the following code, which doesn't fetch me the result I expected.

```
var cDate = "11-05-2016";
var m = cDate.slice(0,2);
var d = cDate.slice(3,2);
var y = cDate.slice(6);
console.log("Month is " + m);
console.log("Day is " + d);
console.log("Year is " + y);
```

This gives the following output:

```
Month is 11
Day is 
Year is 2016
```

I tried to `slice` with different strings. But every time I do it, it always gives me an empty string when I slice it from the middle of the string. Why is this?

Comment: "endSlice
Optional. The zero-based index at which to end extraction. If omitted, slice() extracts to the end of the string. If negative, it is treated as sourceLength + endSlice where sourceLength is the length of the string (for example, if endSlice is -3 it is treated as sourceLength - 3)."

Comment: I want the day printed as 05. It returns an empty string

Comment: 2nd parameter is not the length of slice like it is in `substr`.

Comment: tangentially, I would recommend .split('-') for this sort of thing rather than slice or substr as the numbers are more readable and a little less magical.

`var parts = cDate.split('-'); var m = parts[0]; var d = parts[1]; var y = parts[2];`

Comment: use `slice` when you know the indices of the characters in the string, use `substr` when you know the length of the substring you want

Comment: @BlakeO'Hare Thank you! This looks more elegant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

> The **slice()** method extracts a section of a string and returns a new string.

The syntax of slice is:

> str.slice(beginSlice[, endSlice])

Note that the `endSlice` is the actual position in the string (and **not** how many chars to get from the `beginSlice`).

In your example - you can't slice a string from position 3 to position 2 (because it goes backwards), so you get an empty string.

Comment: //Note that the endSlice is the actual position in the string (and not how many chars to get from the beginning// Oh Ok. I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing `slice` with `substr`. The arguments mean different things:

- `slice( startIndex, endIndex )`
- `substr( startIndex, length )`

```js
var cDate = "11-05-2016";
var m = cDate.substr(0,2); // "11"
var d = cDate.substr(3,2); // "05"
var y = cDate.substr(6); // "2016"
console.log("Month is " + m);
console.log("Day is " + d);
console.log("Year is " + y);
```